# Apache Spark - how to get unmatched rows from two RDDs

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two different RDDs, each RDD have some common fields, based on that fields i want to get unmatched records from RDD1 or RDD2.[Records available in RDD1 but not available in RDD2] [Records available in RDD2 but not available in RDD1]

It seems we could use `subtract` or `subtractbyKey`.

Sample Input:

```
**File 1:**

sam,23,cricket
alex,34,football
ann,21,football

**File 2:**

ruby,25,football,usa
alex,34,cricket,usa
ann,21,cricket,usa

**expected output:**

sam,23,cricket
```

**Update:**

Currently i am using Spark SQL to get the unmatched records from the RDDs(Writing a query to get the unmatched records).

What i am looking is, is it something we can do it with Spark Core itself instead of using Spark SQL and also i am not looking the code, is there any operation available in Spark Core?

Please advise on this.

Regards,
Shankar.

Comment: Some examples? What have you tried so far? Or are you just hoping someone will write your code for you? :)

Comment: Could you add some sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: @maasg added sample data.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bring both RDDs to the same shape and use `subtract` to remove the common elements.

Given `rdd1` from `file1` and `rdd2` from `file2` as presented above, you could do something like:

```
val userScore2 = rdd2.map{case (name, score, sport, country) => (name, score, sport)}

val in1andNotin2 = rdd1 subtract userScore2

val in2andNotIn1 = userScore2 subtract rdd1
```

Comment: Thanks i got it. I will try to do the same on java API.